# Hash segment of URL is cleared on first page load in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I'm using the hash URL strategy for a Flutter Web project. It's working fine, but now I want to be able to go straight to a specific page by specifying a path after the hashtag, for example `myapp.dev/#/login`.

The problem is that if I open a new browser window, enter the URL and press Enter, the URL changes to `myapp.dev/#/` and I end up on the normal start page.

If I then enter the original URL again (in the same window/tab) and press Enter, it works.

How come the URL gets changed to the base URL on the initial page load, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: You can use a routing package to help you with this. Using [qlevar_Router](https://pub.dev/packages/qlevar_router) you can open any page in your app from the URL. For example, [this URL](https://qlevar-router.netlify.app/#/store/4/product/3) will take you to the store 4 with the product 3.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the reason was that I'm showing a splash screen while initialising some things at startup, and that splash screen is displayed in a separate `MaterialApp` than the main app. For some reason, when switching from the splash `MaterialApp` to the real `MaterialApp`, the route information is gone and the URL is reset.

I solved it by implementing `onGenerateRoute` for the splash screen and storing the `RouteSetting` in a variable. Then, in the real `onGenerateRoute` that displays the actual app, I check if that variable is not null, and if so I use that instead of the `RouteSetting` supplied to `onGenerateRoute` (and then I set it to null so it won't be used again).

Perhaps not the cleanest solution, but pretty straight forward and easy to reason about.